# Non constant solutions of the following equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, functional-equations, functional-calculus

In the last class of my subject of mathematics applied to biology the teacher proposed to us to model the density of certain substance. After several hypotheses, that I have decided to omit here in order to make the question more concise, I have obtained the following functional equation:
$$-Af(x)^2+Bf(x)-C\int_{B(x,1)}f(y)dy=0,$$
where A,B,C are positive constants and $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ indicates the density in each point of the plane.
In order to know if the equation that I have found makes sense I was trying to know some solutions. However, I am not able to find solutions that are not constant.  Does anyone know of a method for finding solutions to equations like this? I could set some restriction on the parameters if necessary.

Comment: Presumably the $f(x)$ should be $f(y)$?

Comment: What is $B(x,1)$?

Comment: @copper.hat you're right. Fixed it!

Comment: @Exodd, that term comes from the interaction of the substance with its surrounding area.

Comment: I mean, what is it mathematically? is it a ball with center $x$ and radius 1?

Comment: @Exodd, yes, it is the ball of radius 1 and centered in $x$